# Xamarin forms shell navigation flickering

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app in which I am using shell. The problem I am facing is when I navigate from shell  bottom navigation to any inner page and navigate back to previous page there is a flicker occurring.Please refer the screen record https://drive.google.com/open?id=1861iNlcV7ao6oDUNu7nL4WiyFuWjwXx_.

My Shell Page

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"             
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PaTS.Views"
             x:Class="SampleApp.AppShell">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Dashboard" Icon="icon_dashboard.png" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Dashboard}" />
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Notifications" Icon="icon_notifications.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Dashboard}" />
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Account" Icon="icon_user.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Dashboard}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>


</Shell>
```

**Dashboard page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:sample.CustomRender"
             mc:Ignorable="d"     
             BackgroundColor="#004d6f"
             Title="Dashboard"            
             x:Class="sample.Views.Dashboard">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <!--<Image  Aspect="AspectFill" >
                    <Image.Source>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" Tablet="cover.jpg" Phone="loginbackground_phone.jpg" />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>-->

            <Grid  >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.9*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#004d6f">

                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent"  IsClippedToBounds="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                            <Grid HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <controls:CircleImage                                             
                                             BorderColor="LightBlue"
                                             BorderThickness="2"                                                                      
                                             Source="sampleuser.png"                                               
                                             Aspect="AspectFill">

                                    <Image.Margin>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="20,30,15,0" />
                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="20,15,15,0" />
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Image.Margin>
                                    <Image.HeightRequest>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="60" Phone="30" />
                                    </Image.HeightRequest>

                                </controls:CircleImage>
                                <controls:CircleImage  
                                             x:Name="UserImage"                                            
                                             BorderColor="LightBlue"
                                             BorderThickness="2"                                          
                                             Source="sampleuser.png"   
                                             Aspect="AspectFill">
                                    <Image.Margin>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="20,30,15,0" />
                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="20,15,15,0" />
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Image.Margin>
                                    <Image.HeightRequest>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="60" Phone="30" />
                                    </Image.HeightRequest>

                                </controls:CircleImage>
                            </Grid>
                            <Label Text="Welcome" HorizontalOptions="Start"  VerticalOptions="Center" MaxLines="1"   TextColor="White">
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Regular" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>

                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="14" Phone="11" />
                                </Label.FontSize>

                                <Label.Margin>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,30,0,0" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="0,15,0,0" />
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.Margin>
                            </Label>

                            <Label x:Name="UserName" MaxLines="1" Text="User" HorizontalOptions="Start"  VerticalOptions="Center"   TextColor="LightBlue">
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Regular" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="14" Phone="11" />
                                </Label.FontSize>

                                <Label.Margin>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,30,0,0" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="0,15,0,0" />
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.Margin>
                            </Label>

                        </StackLayout>

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="icon_xamarin_logo.png"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   Margin="0,25,0,0">
                            </Image>

                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Sample App" TextColor="White" FontSize="30" Margin="10,5,10,5" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" >
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Bold" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Bold.ttf#Montserrat-Bold" />
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                            </Label>
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Sample app details™" TextColor="Snow" FontSize="Medium" Margin="10,5,10,10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" >
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Regular" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                            </Label>

                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>

                <Image Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="CurvedMask.jpg" Margin="-6,0,-6,-6"></Image>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="15">

                        <Grid >

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="6">
  <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer
                               Tapped="Timesheet_Tapped"
                               NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Image Source="icon_timesheet.png" Grid.Row="0"></Image>
                                    <Label Text="Timesheets" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Gray">
                                        <Label.FontFamily>
                                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Bold" />
                                                <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Bold.ttf#Montserrat-Bold" />
                                            </OnPlatform>
                                        </Label.FontFamily>
                                    </Label>
                                </Grid>

                            </Frame>

                            <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" CornerRadius="6">

                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Image Source="icon_employee.png" Grid.Row="0"></Image>
                                    <Label Text="Employees" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Gray">
                                        <Label.FontFamily>
                                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Bold" />
                                                <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Bold.ttf#Montserrat-Bold" />
                                            </OnPlatform>
                                        </Label.FontFamily>
                                    </Label>
                                </Grid>

                            </Frame>

                            <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="6">

                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Image Source="icon_graph.png" Grid.Row="0"></Image>
                                    <Label Text="Analysis" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Gray">
                                        <Label.FontFamily>
                                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Bold" />
                                                <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Bold.ttf#Montserrat-Bold" />
                                            </OnPlatform>
                                        </Label.FontFamily>
                                    </Label>
                                </Grid>

                            </Frame>

                            <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" CornerRadius="6">

                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Image Source="icon_info.png" Grid.Row="0"></Image>
                                    <Label Text="Info" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Gray">
                                        <Label.FontFamily>
                                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Bold" />
                                                <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Bold.ttf#Montserrat-Bold" />
                                            </OnPlatform>
                                        </Label.FontFamily>
                                    </Label>
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Page navigation**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Dashboard : ContentPage
{
     public Dashboard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }
    private async void Timesheet_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TimesheetList(),true);                    
    }
}
```

When I navigate to TimesheetList and press back button, It will slide back to dashboard with little flicker. How to resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I test the code you provided. In the Dashboard page, there is no code you used to for Timesheet_Tapped event.

Try the code below, it works well on my side.

```
  <Image Source="icon_timesheet.png" Grid.Row="0" >
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Timesheet_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi , I used Frame.GestureRecognizers . But sorry for not including in the code above. It still have the same issue

Comment: I could not reproduce. Could you upload your code sample on github for me to test?

Comment: Okey bro...please wait

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay.. Please find the repository for testing: https://github.com/tvm-anand/ShellNavigation

Comment: @AndroDevil I check the sample on GitHub. It is not similar to the question you post. Please confirm the code sample on GitHub.

Comment: Hi, Sorry my mistake.. Can you check the repo now?\

Comment: Did you checked bro?

Comment: yes, I check it again, but the code sample on github is still not related to your question. Is this the right sample?

Comment: Yes..can you check the click on first page? Did you feel any flickering?

Comment: If the first page you mean is the ItemsPage, it works well on my side.

Comment: Oh man..it have flickering issue on me.. Is it something related to android support libraries?

Comment: What is the version of your test device and the version of Xamarin.Forms? Try to create a shell template project, do you still get the fickering? Waiting for your feedback, i will test on same environment.

Comment: Hi. I am using honor 8x which runs on android 9.0 and Iam using visual studio 2019 version : 4.8.03761  and xamarin.forms version : 4.3.0.947036.  The issue only in android...Default shell application have no problem.I noticed this problems after adding libraries like  Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils,Xamarin.Android.Support.Design,Xamarin.Android.Support.v4,Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter etc...In ios there is no issue

Comment: Still don't reproduce. How about change animated to false?  `await Navigation.PushAsync(new TimesheetList(), false);` Try this way, maybe helpful.

Comment: Okey..Let me check bro

Comment: Still no luck bro. 

Comment: i think the fickering is not caused by the code, have you try to test on another device?

Comment: Yes I tried it on several devices.It all shows same issue

Comment: Try to repair your Visual Studio, the device is okay, the code is okay, i guess the VS have something wrong.

Comment: Does the repair of VS help you?

Comment: No bro...still I have the same issue...is it something related to vs 2019? did you tested it on real device? I think emulator does not have this issue

Comment: I tested on google pixel 8.1 and emulator. I will keep on searching. If have sonething new, i will feedback ASAP.

Comment: Any success? I have the same issue

Comment: I'm using shell navigation. It is flickering when poping back.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but in the android emulator Android 9.0 fickering not happend, in my case only Samsung s8, s8+, s9, s9+, s10, s10+ devices.

In this bug report: 
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8581

That guy finds a workaround, delete animation:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed() {
    Current.Navigation.PopAsync(false); 
    return true;
}
```